# Identifier must be declared

Tags: shell-script

My snippet :

```
   filename='somefile_Connectivity_12345.CSV'
   trimfilename= echo $filename| cut -d'_' -f 2
   if '$trimfilename'='Connectivity'
   then 
   echo "loop1"
   elif '$trimfilename'='Red'
   then 
echo " loop2"
elif ' $trimfilename'='Blue'
then
echo "loop3'
end if;
```

I am facing an error saying "identifier must be declared.
It worked fine if I didnt have the elif parts in place.

Comment: What shell are you using?  Is `elsif` a typo (the 6th line in your snippet)?

Comment: yes sorry..elsif was a typo

Comment: probably you want `if [ "$trimfile" = something ]` ? same goes for `elif` later... or `if test "$trimfile" = something`...?

Comment: @mikeserv it was a typo..sorry i typed out the code in a hurry ..can u check now

Comment: what shell are you using?

Comment: you can try to shorten your program  but in such a way that the error still will be raised. So you can narrow down the statement where the error occurs.

Comment: [Reposted from Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25332462/identifier-must-be-declared). Please [don't do this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-it-possible-to-post-questions-across-a-couple-of-the-sites-because-its-debata/64073#64073).

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename='somefile_Connectivity_12345.CSV'
trimfilename=$(echo $filename| cut -d'_' -f 2)
if [ $trimfilename = "Connectivity" ]
then 
  echo "loop1"
elif [ $trimfilename = "Red" ]
then 
  echo " loop2"
elif [ $trimfilename = "Blue" ]
then
  echo "loop3"
fi
```

Comment: You should put all variable references (`$filename` and `$trimfilename`) into double quotes. Strictly speaking, you *don't* need to quote simple (one word with no special characters) string constants like `"Red"` and `"Blue"` (but, of course, it doesn't hurt).

Answer (score -1):

Basically you're trying to set '$trimfilename' to 'Connectivity' when you do:

```
if '$trimfilename'='Connectivity'...
```

`if` - when in command position - is *not* a command in the same sense that `echo` and `exit` and even `[` are. It is a *reserved word* - it is handled by the shell's parser in the same way that `;`, `<newline>`, and `! dammit` are - in the same way that `=` is, in fact.

`if` denotes the start of an `if` block, which consists of at least one *compound command*, which is made up of 1 or *simple commands*. Maybe the most helpful way I can describe it is like:

```
#one compound command
{ simple command; simple command; simple command; } 

if { : this compound command returns 0 ; }
then { : do this compound command ; }
else { : do this compound command ; }
fi
```

The braces between each of the *reserved words* `if`, `then`; and `else` are *implied* in an `if` block and are unnecessary. But all are handled by the shell's parser.

Parsing occurs *before* variable expansion/assignment, so when you do:

```
if var=val
then :
else :
fi
```

...you're testing if the *assignment* of *val* to *var* returns 0 - which it will in this case - and then you move on from there. *But*... when you do...

```
if 'in\valid var name'=val
then :
else :
fi
```

...then *if you're lucky* you'll get an error message and your else block completed, though most likely execution of the entire block will halt abruptly because *it cannot be parsed*.

As I said, the `=` assignment operator is a function of the shell's parser, and this is why it takes at least two evaluations to do:

```
var=val; eval $var=val2
```

The shell notes the `=` assignment function at parse time - before the expansion - and it cannot handle assigning to an expansion - *because it hasn't happened yet.*

What you want is to test a command's return value - apparently a command that evaluates a variable's expansion. This is what `test` is for...

```
if test "$var" = "val"
then echo yay
else echo nay
fi
```

or...

```
if [ "$var" = "val" ]
then echo yay
else echo nay
fi
```

It is important to `"quote"` a tested expansion because the `test` command is only equipped to handle so many arguments in so many places - and *after* shell parsing and shell expansions comes *word splitting.*